# Design to method chain across packages

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

So bascially we have a library that contains a series of bifunctions passed in the metadata and datum looking like:
Transform1:

```
package transformation1;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public class Transform1 implements BiFunction<JsonNode, ObjectNode, JsonNode> {

    @Override
    public JsonNode apply(JsonNode metadata, ObjectNode datum) {
        //business logic
    }
}
```

Transform2:

```
package transformation2;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public class Transform2 implements BiFunction<JsonNode, ObjectNode, JsonNode> {

    @Override
    public JsonNode apply(JsonNode metadata, ObjectNode datum) {
        //business logic
    }
}
```

Transform3:

```
package transformation3;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public class Transform3 implements BiFunction<JsonNode, ObjectNode, JsonNode> {

    @Override
    public JsonNode apply(JsonNode metadata, ObjectNode datum) {
        //business logic
    }
}
```

The clients will use transform1, transform2, and some may use transform3. The output of 1 goes to 2 and 2 to 3. So currently a client can just call them individually in order, but I am wondering if there is a way to method chain them similar to say the builder pattern.

So it will be accessed:

```
Transform1 transform1 = new Transform1();
ObjectNode datum1 = transform1.apply(transform1Metadata, datum);
Transform2 transform2 = new Transform2();
ObjectNode datum2 = transform1.apply(transform2Metadata, datum1);
Transform3 transform3 = new Transform3();
ObjectNode datum3 = transform1.apply(transform3Metadata, datum2);
```

But I am wondering is it possible to create another class that would doing akin to a builder pattern for building objects. So something like:

`TransformationBuilder
  .transform1(transform1Metadata)
  .transform2(transform2Metadata)
  .build(datum);`

Comment: @DocBrown does that help?

Comment: Really better now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called [Fluent interface](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_Interface), and it is not restricted to a "Builder".

If `ObjectNode` would be class under your control, you could simply give it methods `transform1`, `transform2` with the required signatures. Since it is a third-party class outside of your control, and Java does not support [C#-like extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359979/java-equivalent-to-c-sharp-extension-methods), your best bet is probably to create a wrapper class `TransformableObjectNode`, along the lines of

```
class TransformableObjectNode
{
      private _node;
      public TransformableObjectNode(ObjectNode node)
      {
        _node=node;
      }
      public TransformableObjectNode transform1(transform1Metadata)
      {
          Transform1 transformer1 = new Transform1();
          _node=transformer1.apply(transform1Metadata,_node);
          return this;
      }
      // ...
      public ObjectNode toObjectNode()
      {
         return _node;
      }
}
```

Usage:

```
 newdatum = new TransformableObjecNode(datum)
              .transform1(transform1Metadata)
              .transform2(transform2Metadata)
               .toObjectNode();
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked like a charm!